# Webpack Encore: How to include js from /vendor and use globally?

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.3, webpack-encore, symfony4

How do I include assets from the /vendor folder so that I can use it globally?

my base.html.twig:

```
<script src="{{ asset('build/vendor.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('build/color-admin.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('build/app.js') }}"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        App.init();
    });
</script>
```

And in my webpack.config I have:

```
.addEntry('color-admin', [
    onePageJSFolder + '/apps.js',
    onePageCSSFolder + '/animate.css',
    onePageCSSFolder + '/style.css',
    onePageCSSFolder + '/style-responsive.css',
    onePageCSSFolder + '/theme/orange.css',
])
```

where onePageJSVolder is a valid url to a /vendor folder:

```
var frontend = './vendor/suvya/color-admin-3/frontend';
var onePage = frontend + '/one-page-parallax/template_content_html';
var onePageAssetsFolder = onePage + '/assets';
var onePagePluginsFolder = onePageAssetsFolder + '/plugins';
var onePageCSSFolder = onePageAssetsFolder + '/css';
var onePageLessFolder = onePageAssetsFolder + '/less';
var onePageJSFolder = onePageAssetsFolder + '/js';
```

But I am getting the error App is undefined. (coming from base.html.twig). App is declared within apps.js but not recognized globally.

How can this be solved?

I am running Symfony-BETA4

Answer (score 1):

Maybe will be better to use the only createSharedEntry for the base.html.twig? 
Look at my example for react app:

```
.createSharedEntry('vendor', [
    'jquery',
    'bootstrap',
    'react',
    'react-dom',
    './node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss'
])
```

It will generate three files, vandor.css, vendor.js and manifest.js.
This flow good described in [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/frontend/encore/shared-entry.html), and about your issue: `inside Webpack, when you require a module, it does not (usually) set a global variable. Instead, it just returns a value:` You need to check global variables. Look [this example](https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/frontend/encore/legacy-apps.html) of resolving jQuery issue with a global variable, and maybe it will help you. As I see you need to add `autoProvideVariables` to your webpack.config.js

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the package you are using has a Resources\Public folder where the assets are stored you can use the command line:

```
php bin/console assets:install
```

By default this will copy all vendors Resource\Public to your web directory. There are more options available in the [Symfony Blog](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-smarter-assets-install-command) covering this. It is considered a [Symfony Best Practice](https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html) to keep all your assets in your web directory. It allows for limited public facing components.

Comment: no im not storing assets in the public folder. they are generated by web pack and then put in the public folder. the links shared and answer given are in no way related to my question.